# Examples of reverse outlining?

Tags: fiction, outline

Here is a link to an article about reverse outlining:  
https://www.helpingwritersbecomeauthors.com/should-you-outline-backwards 
Can anyone share more concrete examples of this technique in fiction writing?

Comment: Isn't this just called '**outlining**'…?

Comment: No, its different.  It is sort of the same idea as analysis in mathematics.  Analysis iwhere you start at the solution of a problem and logically work backward towards the unknowns.  When the beginning is reached, "play the tape forward".  The same is true with writing, but instead of using mathematical logic, "story logic" is used instead.  In other words, knowing the desired ending, work backward to the narrative the initiated it.  This is different than working forward where you can proceed deductively, but whether you will reach the end state is unclear.  You may or may not get lucky.

Comment: @mont2223 In the future, please use the [edit] button below your question to edit in any clarifications.

Answer (score 0):

I have heard many times that the Harry Potter series was reverse outlined like that. JK Rowling knew the whole Voldemort fight at the end before the first line of the first book.

Comment: I think we all saw it coming, tbh.

Comment: @wetcircuit Yes, it's by far the most prevalent example.

Comment: Thank you @MurphyL.for this information.  It is very relevant.  I must clarify my question, though.  Does anyone have an actual case study of where an author used reverse outlining detailing their step by step thought process?  For example, a man wants to cross a river.  How?  Maybe he can walk across a tree spanning a river.  How does he find a tree with this characteristic?  Maybe he cut one down.  How does he cut one down?  He uses an axe like tool.  Where does he find such a tool?  Does he trade with someone for it?  Does he make it himself?  If so, how?  See how the process works?